# What is $\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{x}}$ equal to when $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{x}}$$
What's the output of this function when $x=0$?

I tried graphing it on Desmos and it shows a curve passing through the origin so the output must be equal to zero, however I don't get how it reached this result.

The only way it could have reached it is maybe by changing the equation a little bit:

$$\frac{1\cdot x}{(2+\frac{1}{x})\cdot x}$$ (where $x\neq0$)
$$\frac{x}{2x+{1}}$$

However since we stated in the first step that $x$ can't be equal to zero we can't make it equal to zero again and solve with the simplified version we've just arrived at:

at $x=0$,

$$\frac{0}{0+{1}}=0$$ $\rightarrow$ *so this is wrong*

How did Desmos then arrive at the answer?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ even though the function, as written, is undefined at $0$.  This isn't just a Desmos thing, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F%282%2B1%2Fx%29) also removes the singularity.

Comment: The denominator $\to \infty$, so with a finite numerator, the limit must be $0$.

Comment: You have a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) at $x=0$, though not at $x=-\frac12$

Comment: Here is even simpler one $\dfrac{1}{1/x}.$ The word you should search for is [limit of a function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function)

Comment: Side comment: your original question was "what is $y$ equal to?" when in fact there was no definition of $y$ in your problem. We often see equations in the form $y = [\ldots]$, so one could guess at what you meant, but still, it's better to be clear. Since $y$ doesn't come up again, the simplest thing is not to mention it at all (as per my edit).

Comment: @lulu As a result, our graph shouldn't go through the zero point, right?  So, the coordinate center should be marked as "open circle", right?

Comment: Desmos doesn’t do open circles. I think this is probably because it really is not practical for it to find every missing point of every curve.

Comment: Right, as wonderful a tool as it is, Desmos doesn't always tell the whole story. Here's another example: $xy=0$ should show the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$, but instead it only shows $y=0$.

Comment: @lonestudent  It's pretty standard to remove any removable singularities when graphing rational functions,  I'd have been surprised if WA had done anything else.

Comment: @lulu thank you. I mean lesson time, what should I do if I have to draw this graph by hand?  Should I show the coordinate center as an open circle?

Comment: I'd say you should ask your instructor that.  Leaving an open circle is not incorrect.  I mean, you can defend it.  But, really, it's up to the instructor.

Comment: @lulu thank you very much..Even if it is small, I am trying to teach something within my knowledge.  Yes, I am actually also a student myself..  Because I myself am learning from you.  If my student asks me which is correct, I would like to give him a good answer. That's why I asked you.  For example, open-closed circles are very important when drawing floor and ceiling functions.

Comment: Ah, but there is an important difference:  for floors, say, the singularities are not removable.  That is to say, $\lim_{x\to 1} \lfloor x \rfloor$ does not exist (it is $0$ if you approach from below and $1$ if you approach from above).  that is very different from, say, $\frac xx$ which has a removable singularity at $0$ (indeed, that function is $1$ everywhere except at $0$).

Comment: To stress:  it makes a great deal of sense to require that your students think about singularities.  A good question might be;  "Does the function $\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$ have any singularities?  Are they removable?  "  Or something like that.

Comment: @lulu Many thanks for teaching me! I think the subject I should grasp / learn well is singularities.  Finally, can you give me a source that I can read?On this topic. Could this resource be enough for me?https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)

Comment: Yes... That source looks good.

Comment: @lulu I asked you a lot of questions. Thank you for your patience..I wish you health and well-being.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When $x$ is close to zero, $1/x$ is very large. Hence,
$$
\frac{2}{2+\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{2}{1+\text{very large}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{2}{1+\text{very large}}=\text{very close to $0$} \, .
$$
In the language of limits, we can say that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2}{2+\frac{1}{x}}=0 \, .
$$
But this *doesn't* mean that when $x$ equals $0$,
$$
\frac{2}{2+\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{2}{2+\frac{1}{0}}=0 \, .
$$
The above expression doesn't make any sense, because we are not allowed to divide by zero. What we can say is that as $x$ gets very close to $0$, $2/(2+1/x)$ is also very close to $0$. The graph is misleading: because our eyes cannot discern what happens at a single point, it *looks* as if the curve crosses the origin, even though it does not.

Comment: +1 for an answer written at the level of sophistication suggested by the question.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Ikr! It's really sad and sometimes devestating when I get answers that will only benefit other people with a higher knowledge in math than me. Or answers that would only lead me to more and more questions to answer to be able to understand my original question in first place. Not to mean that I don't appreciate every answer I get, I seriously do because it'll definitely benefit others :)

Comment: @Manar: If you go on to study higher-level mathematics, then you can look back at this post and feel proud that you discovered what a removable singularity is :)

Answer (score 2):

The function is equal to (2x) / (2x+1) except for x=0 where it is not defined. The function isn’t equal to anything when x=0.

Answer (score 1):

Take the limit as x tends to 0 from above, this will be 0 as 1/x tends to infinity. Then take the limit as x tends to 0 from below, this will also be zero, as 1/x tends to minus infinity. Therefore, despite the fact the function has no value at x = 0, arbitrarily close to x=0 from any direction (0-delta, 0+delta), the function will approach 0.